# StoredProcedureQuery executeUpdate is returning 0 even after successfully updating the values in the table without exception

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Facing issues in the below code.
Even after updating the table values successfully without exception the value of executeUpdate is coming as zero.
Anything missing in the code

Using spring boot and JPA spring boot version 2.7.16

```
private int inserDetails(List<SPBatchRow> rows , String storedProcedureName) throws Exception {
        int executeUpdate = 0;
        EntityManager entityManager = null;
        EntityTransaction transaction = null;
        try {
            entityManager = databaseManager.getEntityManager();
            transaction = entityManager.getTransaction();
            transaction.begin();
                for(SPBatchRow row : rows) {
                    StoredProcedureQuery storedProcedure = entityManager.createStoredProcedureQuery(storedProcedureName);
                    setParameters(row, storedProcedure);
                    executeUpdate = storedProcedure.executeUpdate();
                }
            transaction.commit();
            
            LOGGER.info("[SPDatabaseConnector] : [inserLogDetails] success........ " + executeUpdate);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            executeUpdate = 0;
            LOGGER.error("[SPDatabaseConnector] : [inserLogDetails] : [Exception] : ", e);
            if(transaction.isActive()) {
                transaction.rollback();
            }
            throw e;
        } finally {
            if (entityManager != null) {
                entityManager.close();
            }
        }
        return executeUpdate;
    }
```